# Can't set Diagnostic Settings on Function App using Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-bicep

I have a Bicep module to create a Function app and its Diagnostic Settings, and after a successful deployment, I saw that the 'Diagnostic Setting' menu on the Portal is greyed out - see linked image as I still can't embed images yet :-).

[image: Function App Diagnostic Setting greyed out]

However, as part of the deployment I also created a Slot (staging) for the Function app, and the Staging instance has its 'Diagnostic Setting' menu enabled, and I can go, view and edit these settings - again see linked image.

[image: Function App Slot Diagnostic Setting NOT greyed out]

Does anyone know why this is the case?  These App Service instances do not have anything deployed to them, so they are both 'empty'

Here is the code that deploys these:

```
resource app 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2020-12-01' = {
  name: appName
  location: location
  tags: {
    'hidden-link: /app-insights-resource-id': appInsightsId
    Customer: customerName
    Environment: environment
    Project: projectName
  }
  kind: 'functionapp'
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: appServerFarmId
    siteConfig: {
      alwaysOn: false
      http20Enabled: true
    }
    httpsOnly: true
  }
}

resource diagSettingsApp 'Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings@2021-05-01-preview' = {
  scope: app
  name: 'diagsetting-${app.name}'
  properties: {
    workspaceId: lawId
    logs: [
      {
        category: 'FunctionAppLogs'
        enabled: true
      }
    ]
    metrics: [
      {
        category: 'AllMetrics'
        enabled: true
      }
    ]
  }
}

resource appSlot 'Microsoft.Web/sites/slots@2020-12-01' = {
  name: '${app.name}/staging'
  location: location
  tags: {
    Customer: customerName
    Environment: environment
    Project: projectName
  }
  kind: 'functionapp'
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: appServerFarmId
    siteConfig: {
      http20Enabled: true
      appSettings: [
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_DNS_SERVER'
          value: '168.63.129.16'
        }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL'
          value: '1'
        }
      ]
    }
    httpsOnly: true
  }
}

resource diagSettingsAppSlot 'Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings@2021-05-01-preview' = {
  scope: appSlot
  name: 'diagsetting-${app.name}-staging'
  properties: {
    workspaceId: lawId
    logs: [
      {
        category: 'FunctionAppLogs'
        enabled: true
      }
    ]
    metrics: [
      {
        category: 'AllMetrics'
        enabled: true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Try asking in azure bicep GitHub discussions. Microsoft team is monitoring the repo discussions and you may get a response there. https://github.com/Azure/bicep/discussions Also, if you have a support plan - submit a ticket - they will definitely try to help you.

Comment: In case if you don't have the support plan then please let us know.