Diagnostic settings for FunctionApp in ARM template
I am trying to create an ARM template that deploys a workspace and an Azure Function App with Diagnostic Settings defined to write to that workspace (not to a storage account). I did that manually in the Portal, but as I said, I need the ARM template.
I have looked through the Microsoft documentation, but there are no examples for this specific configuration that I have found (there are for other resource types, but I haven't been successful trying to extrapolate those examples to my use case)
I have already tried exporting the ARM for the full resource group (a test resource group I created to have only these resources inside) and it is not there. I also tried exporting the ARM template for just the Function App with the diagnostic settings already created, but once again there is no mention of such settings. I see the Diagnostic settings itself have a "View JSON" in the portal, which I used as a guide to include in my ARM templates.
This is the base ARM template I am using (some things are hardcoded just for testing purposes. Once it works I will turn them into variables/parameters)
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "variables": {
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "hostingPlanName": "[variables('functionAppName')]",
    "storageAccountName": "[concat('sometest', variables('location'))]",
    "storageAccountType": "Standard_LRS",
    "logAnalyticsWorkspaceName": "[concat('sometest-', variables('location'), '-loganalytics')]",
    "functionAppName": "[concat('sometest-', variables('location'))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "name": "[variables('storageAccountName')]",
      "apiVersion": "2022-09-01",
      "location": "[variables('location')]",
      "kind": "StorageV2",
      "sku": {
        "name": "[variables('storageAccountType')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "apiVersion": "2021-02-01",
      "name": "[variables('hostingPlanName')]",
      "location": "[variables('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "EP2",
        "tier": "ElasticPremium",
        "size": "EP2",
        "family": "EP",
        "capacity": 1
      },
      "kind": "elastic",
      "properties": {
        "perSiteScaling": false,
        "elasticScaleEnabled": true,
        "maximumElasticWorkerCount": 100,
        "isSpot": false,
        "reserved": false,
        "isXenon": false,
        "hyperV": false,
        "targetWorkerCount": 0,
        "targetWorkerSizeId": 0,
        "zoneRedundant": false
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces",
      "apiVersion": "2021-12-01-preview",
      "name": "[variables('logAnalyticsWorkspaceName')]",
      "location": "[variables('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "features": {
          "enableLogAccessUsingOnlyResourcePermissions": true
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
      "name": "[variables('functionAppName')]",
      "location": "[variables('location')]",
      "kind": "functionapp",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('hostingPlanName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName'))]"
      ],
      "identity": {
        "type": "SystemAssigned"
      },
      "properties": {
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('hostingPlanName'))]",
        "httpsOnly": true,
        "http20Enabled": true,
        "use32BitWorkerProcess": false,
        "enabled": true,
        "siteConfig": {
          "functionAppScaleLimit": 100
        }
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "type": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings",
          "name": "aga-test-eastus-diags",
          "apiVersion": "2022-09-01",
          "dependsOn": [
            "/subscriptions/a68cb0e1-b284-49e1-9051-f8d5c6485a3d/resourcegroups/myResourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/sometest-eastus",
            "/subscriptions/a68cb0e1-b284-49e1-9051-f8d5c6485a3d/resourcegroups/myResourceGroupName/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/sometest-eastus-loganalytics"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "workspaceId": "/subscriptions/a68cb0e1-b284-49e1-9051-f8d5c6485a3d/resourcegroups/myResourceGroupName/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/sometest-eastus-loganalytics",
            "logs": [
              {
                "category": "FunctionAppLogs",
                "categoryGroup": null,
                "enabled": true,
                "retentionPolicy": {
                  "days": 0,
                  "enabled": false
                }
              }
            ],
            "logAnalyticsDestinationType": null
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

I have tried the following variations with no success:

Having the diagnosticSettings inside the workspace
Having the diagnosticSettings inside the function app
Adding/Removing an id, the scope, the workspaceId
Deploying all the other resources, and then a new deployment with just the diagnosticSettings in the ARM template

Some errors I encountered:

"The resource type '/' does not support diagnostic settings." => generally fixed that by readding the scope
The diagnostic settings is said to have deployed successfully but doesn't appear on the resource group resouces list, nor in the diagnostic settings of the workspace (but if I click right after the deployment has finished in the diagnostic settings resource link, it takes me to a diagnostic settings (kind of weird, I don't understand what a diagnostic settings on its own can be)
Most times, the Function App has the Diagnostic settings menu grayed out when deployed through the ARM template, which makes it impossible to even check if the Diagnostic settings is there, or manually create a new one. This doesn't happen when I manually create the Function App through the portal (which makes me think there's no a role issue)

This is what I am trying to achieve through the ARM template:
Function App resource

Diagnostic settings screen

EDIT: To illustrate further, I tried the approach in an answer below with the diagnostic settings apparently being correctly deployed, but the function app has the diagnostic settings menu grayed out so I can't edit or confirm the diagnostic settings are applied to it, and if I click on the diagnostic settings itself on the deployment result, it looks like a "floating" diagnostic settings not applied to anything at all.
This is the snippet I used:
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/providers/diagnosticSettings",
      "name": "[concat('agatest','/Microsoft.Insights/', 'agatest', 'site')]",
      "apiVersion": "2021-05-01-preview",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', 'agatest')]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces', 'agatest')]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "workspaceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces', 'agatest')]",
        "logs": [
          {
            "category": "FunctionAppLogs",
            "categoryGroup": null,
            "enabled": true,
            "retentionPolicy": {
              "days": 0,
              "enabled": false
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }

Function App with grayed diagnostic settings menu

"Floating" diagnostic settings

EDIT 2: The issue with the Diagnostic settings menu being grayed out was that the Function app didn't have the FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION environment variable set, so it defaulted to ~1, which means V1 Free Tier, which doesn't allow for diagnostic settings. The solution was to set it to ~4. It was done by adding a new resource within the functionapp resource defined like this:
        {
          "name": "appsettings",
          "type": "config",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('functionAppName'))]"
          ],
          "properties": "[variables('environmentVars')]"
        }

Being 'environmentVars' a variable defined as such in the variables section:
"environmentVars": {
    "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION": "~4"
}


You need to use something like this:
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/providers/diagnosticSettings",
    "name": "[concat(variables('functionAppName'), '/Microsoft.Insights/', 'aga-test-eastus-diags')]",
    "apiVersion": "2021-05-01-preview",
    "properties": {
        "workspaceId": "/subscriptions/a68cb0e1-b284-49e1-9051-f8d5c6485a3d/resourcegroups/myResourceGroupName/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/sometest-eastus-loganalytics",
        "logs": [
            {
                "category": "FunctionAppLogs",
                "enabled": true,
                "retentionPolicy": {
                    "days": 0,
                    "enabled": false
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}


Yes, I had tried that. I needed to add explicit dependency on both the function app & the workspace to make it work, and it ends up with the diagnostic settings being deployed. However, the function app has the diagnostic settings menu item grayed out so I can't see the correct configuration for the diagnostic apps within it. And if I click on the diagnostic settings itself on the deployment, it looks like a "floating" diagnostic settings, not being applied to anything at all. I will update the question to show the screenshots.

Yes, dependencies are required - I hadn't added them as I gathered you could do it yourself :) Not sure why it's greyed out - seems to be another issue though, similar to this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73955006/. But you can actually check if Function App logs are being collected in the workspace. It's quite possible the provided answer solves the original issue from your question, and now you have to deal with a new issue - it would warrant creating a new question rather than mix 2 distinct issues in one question.

I just mentioned it for anyone coming here afterwards, so they have more context. The issue is resolved, diagnostic settings option was grayed out due to the FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION environment variable not being set, which defaulted to 1, and V1 is the free tier which doesn't allow for diagnostic settings. I wish the Portal had been more explict about this than a tooltip over the option. I accepted your answer. Thank you!
